# What is the difference between CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE and CRC-16/X-25?

Tags: c, smartcard, crc, nxp-microcontroller

I want to implement CRC-16/X-25. I have a code written in C for CRC-16/CCITT_FALSE, but I don't know what changes do I need to make in that code for CRC-16/X-25 implementation?

The code I am using for CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE is given below:

```cpp
#include  <msp430.h>

#define CRC_POLYNOMIAL      0x1021
#define USHORT_TOPBIT       0x8000

short crc_ret;

// function initialisation

unsigned short crc16(const char *buf, unsigned int buf_len)
{

    unsigned short ret = 0xFFFF;        // Initial Value
    int bit = 8;

    do {
        if (!buf) {
            break;
        }
        unsigned int i = 0;
        for (i=0; i<buf_len; ++i) {
            ret = (unsigned short)(ret ^ ((unsigned short)buf[i] >> 8));
            for (bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
            {
                if (ret & USHORT_TOPBIT)
                    ret = (unsigned short)((ret >> 1) ^ CRC_POLYNOMIAL);
                else
                    ret = (unsigned short)(ret >> 1);
            }
        }
    } while (0);
    return ret;
 }

int main(void)
{
  PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;               // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
                                      // previously configured port settings

  char buf[16];


  buf[0] = 0x5A;                    //buf[0], buf[1] and buf[2] are data bytes

  buf[1] = 0xCF;
  buf[2] = 0x00;



  crc_ret = crc16(buf, 3);   // Calling CRC function

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the website below, CRC16/CCITT_FALSE doesn't match your code. The website indicates it's a left shifting (non-reflected) CRC, while your code is right shifting.

CRC16/X25 is a right shifting (reflected) CRC, and returns ~CRC (CRC xor 0xFFFF). I don't know if this is the same as CRC16/CCITT_X25.

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

You can use the website to compare your results with it's results.

I started with a simple example to create the two crc16 functions:

```
uint16_t crc16_ccitt_false(char* pData, int length)
{
    int i;
    uint16_t wCrc = 0xffff;
    while (length--) {
        wCrc ^= *(unsigned char *)pData++ << 8;
        for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
            wCrc = wCrc & 0x8000 ? (wCrc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : wCrc << 1;
    }
    return wCrc;
}

uint16_t crc16_x25(char* pData, int length)
{
    int i;
    uint16_t wCrc = 0xffff;
    while (length--) {
        wCrc ^= *(unsigned char *)pData++ << 0;
        for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
            wCrc = wCrc & 0x0001 ? (wCrc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : wCrc >> 1;
    }
    return wCrc ^ 0xffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. In these two functions that you have written, can I change my polynomial from 0x8408 to 0x1021? Because my polynomial is 0x1021.

Comment: @RazaJaved - for X25, the bits are reversed, the most significant bit is bit 0, and both the data bytes and the CRC are shifted right as they are cycled, so the polynomial also needs to be reversed so it's most significant bit is bit 0 (ignoring the x^16 term which is implied to be 1 by the code testing for (wCrc & 0x001) before right shifting), which ends up as 0x8408.